# Who runs the awaitable in an Async Await context

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, async-await, threadpool

I've been reading, and I noticed that Async/Await doesn't necessarily create a new thread, when it runs on I/O or any other hardware components.

But what happens when the operation is CPU Bound?

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private static List<string> _logs = new List<string>();

        public Form1()
        {
            Print("Form constructor");
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Print("Caller");
            await SomeLongOperation();
        }

        private async Task SomeLongOperation()
        {
            Print("Called");
            await Task.Delay(10000);
            Print("Called after task");
        }

        public void Print(string txt)
        {
            _logs.Add($"I'm writing from thread {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}. And, {txt}");
        }
    }
```

Let's say I have this class, if the Main Thread calls the button1_Click method runs up to the awaitable, and then the rest of the method is queued on the message loop, and thus allowing the main thread continue to work, then who is running the awaitable, since the main thread is already working on the UI and waiting for the awaitable to complete.

Comment: *thread is already working on the UI and waiting for the awaitable* there is no waiting there

Comment: So you are basically asking where the `await Task.Delay(10000);` is running. Do you consider this specific operation to be CPU-bound? If so, why?

Comment: Just use the debugger.  Debug > New Breakpoint > Function Breakpoint and type "Task.Delay".  Run the program and when it breaks look at Debug > Windows > Call stack.  That's pretty boring, much more convoluted is how it resumes running after the Delay call.  Set a breakpoint on the Print statement.  Use the reference source to make sense of what you see, the comments in the source code are mildly enlightning.

Comment: also it is not "CPU bond" example `Task.Delay` is implemented with `System.Timer` which prolly using some interrupt so ... it's hardware ...

Comment: @TheodorZoulias, yes. That's my question, where the does the Task.Delay run, or any other CPU expensive operation?

Comment: On new thread if you use `Task.Run` .. again `Task.Delay` is not CPU-bound ...

Comment: *"where the does the Task.Delay run"* - [There is no thread](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html)

Comment: Ok. But what if I had an async for loop calculating an int, without Task.Run? Who would run that? So if Task.Delay gets the interupt, let's imagine it's a CPU expense operation WITHOUT Task.Run

Comment: @GabrielLuci I understand that I/O operations have no thread. But what happens when it's a CPU expensive operation?

Comment: You need to start new task there is no way to "await" non "hardware task" without new thread

Comment: @MatthewAlmeida `Task.Delay` isn't an CPU operation.

Comment: @GabrielLuci he should know this ... I've already write this 3 times

Comment: The `Task.Delay` is not a CPU-bound operation. You can launch 1,000,000 concurrent `Task.Delay` operations, and your CPU will be idle. If your question is about CPU-bound operations, you should present a suitable example. Otherwise, what are we supposed to answer?

Comment: "You need to start new task there is no way to "await" non "hardware task" without new thread"

This makes way more sense now!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're confusing "asynchronous" with "parallel".

- Asynchronous means that the thread is freed up to do other things while it is waiting for something else. It's about how your code *waits*.
- Parallel is when two parts of your code are running at the same time. This can only be done with multiple threads. It's about how your code *runs*.

Your example code is asynchronous, but not parallel. Everything is done on one thread. `Task.Delay` is not a CPU operation. There is nothing for the thread to do. [There is no thread](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html).

If you truly had some CPU-intensive operation to run, you can offload that to another thread with `Task.Run`. For example:

```
await Task.Run(() => DoSomethingIntensive());
```

That mixes the idea of asynchronous with parallel. `DoSomethingIntensive()` is run on a separate thread. That's parallel. But the main thread waits asynchronously, meaning that it is free to go and do other things (like respond to user input) while it waits for the other thread to do its thing.

Answer (score -1):

The `async` and `await` keywords doesn't actually cause additional creation of threads. Async methods don't require multithreading because an async method doesn't run on its own thread. The method  actually runs on the current synchronization context and uses time on the thread **only when the method is active**. Developers can use `Task.Run` to move CPU-bound work tasks to a background thread. having said that, a background thread doesn't help with a process that's just waiting for results to become available.

More about `async/await` and threading can be found here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/?view=aspnetcore-2.2#automatic-http-400-responses -

Comment: Ok. I've read this, but it doesn't explain to me whether this runs seperately from the UI/Main thread or not.

Comment: But your code now it just the same as `Print("Caller");Print("Called"); start System.Timer` and then when timer ticks `Print("Called after task");`

Comment: The [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/?view=aspnetcore-2.2#automatic-http-400-responses) included in this answer is irrelevant to the question IMHO.